# 'Like' button click fails in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, facebook, facebook-like

I'm adding a Facebook 'like' button to the DOM using this jQuery plugin: http://onerutter.com/open-source/jquery-facebook-like-plugin.html

It works fine in all browsers except Firefox. The way it works is that when a certain link is clicked, some data is loaded including the URL for the 'Like' button to use, so a new Like button is generated and added to the DOM.

So in Firefox, it's rendered but when I click on it, nothing happens. This is happening on multiple machines with Firefox.

Strangely though, after a Firefox restart in which an Addon has been disabled, suddenly the Like button works, but as soon as you refresh the page it won't!

What could be happening? This is seriously confusing. It's Firefox 3.6.10 by the way.

Thanks :)

Comment: I've discovered that it is actually caching something, but can't figure out what.

Comment: are there any console errors?

Comment: Use the firebug plugin debugger to step through your javascript and see if you are getting an error

Comment: There were no errors guys, but thanks for the suggestions. I figured out the problem anyway, I'll post in a sec :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually hiding the div which the like button was being rendered in and the callback the div was being faded in in *another* callback, one for a fadeout of a loading graphic. Apparently, in Firefox, Facebook JS has a problem with properly setting up the button when its being faded in from a callback of a fadeout.

It's probably a scope error. Anyway, solved :)